# K-means validation

Tags: clustering, cross-validation

If anyone knows a suitable approach to validate cluster solution, I will be glad if the person share with me. I am conducting a research using k-means and partition gave me two groups. The second part is the validation part. I am confuse because now because there are many validation approaches out there. My reason is to validate cluster solution to examine which variable contribute to the separation.

I was thinking of using discriminant function analysis but later realized that my data might not be able to meet all the assumptions underlying that technique. My second thought was logistic regression because of its assumption free property.

Is there any approach out there which is generally accepted for cluster and why?